# Extensions for the Zune software

Tags: plugins, zune, zune-software

Are there any extensions, plugins or addins available for the Zune software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't belive the Zune software provides an infrastructure for plug-ins. I'd love to write some but I can't figure out how to use the API (I'm not sure you're meant to)

Comment: I hoped some company maybe had access to the API.

Comment: ya, @David Hayes is right.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the client software, or the device software?  For the device, you can develop games using the [XNA framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/xna/default.aspx).  Those "games" can interact with most of the content on the device (except DRM protected content).

Answer (score 2):

**[Zuse](http://zusefm.org/)**, a "plugin" of sorts to send play info to Last.fm. See info at the [Zuse Last.fm group](http://www.last.fm/group/Zuse).

It appears to now get the info directly from the Zune software. Previously it read the info from zune.net RSS feeds.

Source code is available.

There is **an API** for the Zune software, but as of yet it's undocumented. See [Tom Fuller's SOA pitstop article](http://soapitstop.com/blogs/fleamarket/archive/2008/03/03/read-the-zune-collection-in-net-from-zune-s-own-api.aspx).